# OpenLDAP compile switches

Tags: configuration, ldap, openldap, opensuse

How can I see how the OpenLDAP executable provided by my distribution (OpenSuSE) was compiled ?

After long debugging, I think that my TLS config is simply ignored. I would like to check if slapd was compiled with --with-tls or not. Is there any way to see what is compiled into the executable ?

slapd -VVV only shows overlays and backends, but tells me nothing about TLS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking in the source RPMs from http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/network:/ldap:/OpenLDAP:/RE24/openSUSE_11.2/src/

The openldap2-2.4.25-141.1.src.rpm gives this for the build configuration in the openldap2.spec file.

```
%configure \
        --localstatedir=/var/run/slapd \
        --libexecdir=/usr/lib/openldap \
        --enable-wrappers \
        --enable-spasswd \
        --enable-modules \
        --enable-shared \
        --enable-dynamic \
        --with-tls \
        --with-cyrus-sasl \
        --enable-crypt \
        --enable-ipv6=yes \
%if "%{name}" == "openldap2"
        --enable-aci \
        --enable-bdb \
        --enable-hdb \
        --enable-rewrite \
        --enable-ldap=yes \
        --enable-meta=mod \
        --enable-monitor=yes \
        --enable-perl=mod \
        --enable-sql=mod \
        --enable-slp \
        --enable-overlays=mod \
        --enable-syncprov=yes \
        --enable-ppolicy=yes \
%else
        --disable-slapd \
%endif
        --enable-lmpasswd \
        --with-yielding-select
```

Looking at the 8th flag down, I see --with-tls specified.

If you need the configuration for a different release of openSuSE, I'm sure you can find a similar line in another source RPM, however, I doubt that the compile flags change very much from release to release.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the SRPM and examine the spec file. Being linked against the SSL shared library is a good indication that it is:

```
$ ldd /usr/sbin/slapd | grep ssl
libssl.so.6 => /lib64/libssl.so.6 (0x00002b1e90a8b000)
```

Comment: This is an indication that the library is included, but it doesn't necessarily mean that slapd has the code to use it enabled.